# How to select group based on the order of rows within group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, tidyverse, data-wrangling

For example, I have the following dataframe:

| ID | variable | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 2 | b | 3 |
| 3 | b | 1 |
| 3 | a | 2 |

I would like to keep only the ID groups where "a" appears before "b" (i.e., the "order" of a is smaller than b). So the result would look something like this:

| ID | variable | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 2 | a | 2 |
| 2 | b | 3 |

Where only ID 1 and 2 remain (with all of its original rows), and all rows in ID 3 are removed because the "order" of b is smaller than a. Would anyone have guidance on how this could be done in R?

Comment: In group 2, the first `b` has `order = 1`, so the rule for dealing with multiple values of `order` associated with `b` within a single group need clarification.  Similarly for multiple values of `a`.  For example, what would happen with `order = 1:4` associates with `variable = c{"b", "a", "a", "b")`.

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying. As long as the group contains any "a" right before "b", the entire group would remain. So that is why group 2 would remain, and the group that you described would also remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(variable == "a" & lead(variable, default = "not b") == "b"))
```

This ignores the `order` column and is based on the order of rows within each ID group. It check for the presence of an `"a"` on one row AND a `"b"` on the immediate next row.

In your comment you say *'"a" right before "b"'* - I went with that *"right before"* clarification. If a group has values `"a", "c", "b"` it would not be kept in my answer as the "a" is not **"right before"** the "b".